# CakePHP 2 access to model constant from controller method

Tags: php, cakephp, constants

I have a Cakephp 2 model with a class constant:

```
class Person extends AppModel 
{
    const NAME = 'MyName';  
}
```

How can i access this class constant into the controller method ?

I try :

```
public function SayName( $id )
{
   var_dump($this->Person->NAME);
   die;
}
```

But the result was : NULL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also declare your model usage at the top of the controller with the command

```
App::uses('Person', 'Model');
```

Then you can access the model constant in the controller with

```
Person::NAME
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit strange, but you'll want to do this:

```
$person = $this->Person;
var_dump($person::NAME);
```

PHP doesn't like the format `$this->inst::CONSTANT`, so simply setting it as a variable (like above) will do the trick.